# vuejs: Split in columns a list of items

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I new on vuejs, I need to split in columns a list of checkboxes, four by column for example.

If I have between 1-4 items will be one column
If I have between 5-8 items will be two columns
and so on

this is my code:

```
<v-card flat class="my-0">
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-checkbox
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item._id"
      :label="item.name"
      :value="item._id"
    ></v-checkbox>
  </v-container>
</v-card>
```

Comment: Try using grid :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<v-checkbox
  v-for="item in items.slice(0, 4)"
  :key="item._id"
  :label="item.name"
  :value="item._id"
></v-checkbox>

<div v-if="items.size > 4"> 
  <v-checkbox
    v-for="item in items.slice(5, items.size)"
    :key="item._id"
    :label="item.name"
    :value="item._id"
 ></v-checkbox>
</div>
```

And you add styling to both the v-checkboxes to display them in columns with the grid system. If you need more columns you just slice again from 5 to 8, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, the only change I did was "items.length > 4".